# Cannot create vue project using vue/cli

Tags: vue.js

**Version vue: 3.7.0**

When I type in CMD:

**vue create "projectname"**

I get the following response:

```
assert.js:85
  throw new AssertionError(obj);
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 5895 == 0
    at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\Users\mikag\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:160:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:475:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

[CMD SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwR57.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with NodeJS v12.1.0, as it is supposed to be fixed by now. 
This is one of the known issues, as per: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3883

Comment: That didn't fix the problem, I still get the same error.

Comment: Was there a solution by now? I get the same error.